# Searching multiple line text that doesn't contain certain expression

Tags: c#, regex, string

The way we log handled exceptions in our program is calling our `Logger` class on the `catch` block.

We found out that couple of our try/catch blocks are missing this logger. I want to create a regex to find out where are those blocks that contain a `catch` block without a calling the `Logger` class.

With my limited knowledge with regex I've came up with this:

```
catch[\s\S]+?{[\s\S]+?(?!log)[\s\S]+?}
```

But it seems that this one returns *any* catch block instead of those *not containing* the word 'log' inside of them.

What am I doing wrong / how can I fix my regex?

**Edit**

Wanted code (regex should **not** return this)

```
catch (SomeException e)
{
    Log(e);
}
```

Bad code (regex should return this)

```
catch (SomeException e)
{
    //Something
}
```

Comment: an example would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small change would help you

```
/catch[^{]+{(?![^}]+log)[^}]+}/i
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mJ0eV3/1)

**Changes made**

- Rather using `[\s\S]` lets be little be more specific using `[^{]` and `[^}]` which are negated character classes which wont match anything in the class.
- move the `[^}]` into the look ahead. Now `(?![^}]+log)` ensures that there is no `log` within the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
catch[^{]*{(?:(?!\blog\b|})[\s\S])*}
```

Try this with flag `i` or ignorecase.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/29